# How do I store order of a sortable multiselect with select2-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-sortable, select2-rails

I have a ton of many-to-many relationships in a CMS I built for work.  I am currently using [Select2 3.5.3](http://select2.github.io/select2/) to assign these relationships.  This all works well.  My issue is attempting the make them drag and drop sortable and store the result of this in the database.

I got the  [Select2 Drag and Drop Sorting](http://select2.github.io/select2/#drag_drop) section demo working in my forms, but I don't quite understand how I would make this dynamic like the rest of my select2 instances  -- in my simple implementation I initialize select2 on anything with the `.select2` class.  I also don't understand how I would store order in the db.

I have an example below modified from an old Ryan Bates update function.  In this example I am attempting to update the Case Study model relationship with the Site model.  Case Study and Site have standard *has-and-belongs-to-many* relationships with each other.

### Models

#### sites.rb

```
  has_many :case_studies_sites
  has_many :case_studies, :through => :case_studies_sites
```

#### case_study.rb

```
  has_many :case_studies_sites
  has_many :sites, :through => :case_studies_sites
```

### Update Function

...how I think it would be accomplished.  One other important point to note: I have added a `position:integer` field to the case_studies_sites table.

```
def select2_sort
    self.case_studies.each_with_index do |id, index|
      CaseStudiesSite.where(case_study_id: id).update_all({position: index+1})
    end
  end
```

### Forms and JS

#### sites/_form.html.erb

Here is an example of the sites form.

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :case_study, "Related Case Studies" %>
      <%= f.collection_select :case_study_ids, CaseStudy.all, :id, :title, {}, {class: 'select2 form-control', multiple: true} %>
   </div>
```

#### sites.js.coffee

And finally here is the coffee script I am currently using to run the basic select2.

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  $('.select2').select2()
```

Both the form fields and JS are currently set for the standards select2 (aka not sortable) as I have not figured out how to translate the select2 demo to these fields.